# Running python scripts from a command line makes window pop and close immediately

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command-line

I created a test file called `pythonScript.py` and I also created a batch file called `pythonScript.bat`. Both of these files are in my `C:\Python Programs` file that a created to store my scripts. The contents of `pythonScript.bat` is: `@py.exe C:\Python Programs\pythonScript.py %*`. When I press `Ctrl+R` and type `pythonScript` a command box pops up and then closes just as quick as it opened. I'm running Windows 10. Any advice?

Comment: Append a line `pause` to the batch file...

Comment: I then get this error: `C:\Python34\python.exe: can't open file 'C\Python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Press any key to continue  .  .  .`     I have also added the `C:\Python Programs` to the Windows `PATH`.

Comment: Seems that you have to enclose `C:\Python Programs\pythonScript.py` in your batch file within a pair of `"`...

Comment: Thanks That worked perfectley!

Comment: Why are you using a batch file instead of putting the command line in a Windows shortcut?

Comment: Also, why are you running via py.exe instead of running "C:\Python Programs\pythonScript.py" directly? Your installation is broken if .py files aren't correctly associated with py.exe. You should be able to add  the "C:\Python Programs" directory to `PATH` and just run `pythonScript.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the path to the Python script in `pythonScript.bat` within double-quotes:

```
@py.exe "C:\Python Programs\pythonScript.py" %*
```

This is because it contains a space. Without the `""`, `py.exe` receives two command line arguments `C:Python` and `Programs\pythonScript.py`.